# "A man is standing outside/on the outside of my house"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, grammaticality, word-order

"A man is standing outside of my house" or "A man is standing on the outside of my house"?

"I will paint outside of my house" or "I will paint on the outside of my house".

Could you pls tell me if I Should  use "On the" or not?

Answer (score 5):

In neither case should you use "on", though it would be grammatically correct.

If the man is standing "on" the outside of the house that would suggest to me that he is standing on the vertical walls of the house, like a fly.

If you paint "on" the outside of the house, that suggests to me that you are using the walls like a canvas to produce a painting or mural.

On the other hand, if you "paint outside your house" that means you do a painting (on paper?) in the open air outside your house.

But if you mean that the man is standing on the ground outside your house then "Standing outside my house", or if you mean that you painting the walls a solid colour then "painting the outside of my house", with no "on".

Comment: however we do say "He's on the outside, looking in."

Comment: "I will paint outside my house" could mean that you are going to make a painting (on a canvas or a sheet of paper) while standing in front of your house.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. A man is standing outside of my house
> 2. A man is standing on the outside of my house.
> 3. I will paint outside of my house
> 4. I will paint on the outside of my house

Eliminate **‘on the’** in sentence 2, and eliminate **‘of’** in sentences 1-3.
Sentence 3 “I will paint outside my house” suggests that the speaker is doing a painting outdoors.
In sentence 4, also eliminate *on*, but leave the preposition *of* .

4. I will paint **the** outside **of** my house

*[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/outside)* provides this example

> The **outside of** the house needs painting.

and includes the [following notations](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/outside)

## Outside

> *Outside* is an adverb, an adjective, a preposition or a noun.
>
> We use *outside* as an adverb or an adjective to mean ‘not in a building’:
> “It was sunny *outside*, but not very warm.” (adverb)
> “It’s a bit dark at night. We could put an outside light there.” (adjective)
> […]
> *Outside* as a noun is used to refer to the exterior of something. It is more informal than *exterior*:
> ***“The **outside** of the house** is not very attractive, but inside it is beautiful.”* (or, more formal, *The exterior of the house* …)

Interesting to note that a number of sources; [here](https://www.antimoon.com/forum/t16889.htm) and [here](https://grammarhow.com/outside-or-outside-of/), claim that “outside of” is American English while British English speakers will generally not use ‘of’
e.g. […outside of the city…](https://A%20large%20percentage%20of%20the%20residents%20must%20and%20do%20work%20outside%20of%20the%20city.) (US)

> OK, we think “outside the hotel” is more elegant, but we don’t think “outside of” is wrong here, and neither, apparently, do most Americans.” […] the dictionary [OED] recognizes “outside of” as entirely normal when used in the spatial sense, defined as “beyond the walls, limits, or bounds of; to or on the outside of; external to.” *[Grammarphobia.com](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2015/04/outside-of.html)*

Perhaps the scenario below will help to clarify

**Aiko**: Where are you?
**Benjiro**: *I'm [standing] **outside** [your house]*.
**Aiko**: Why did you come without warning me? I'm so embarrassed. My house needs to be repainted.
**Benjiro**: *It's not that bad. I'll paint **the outside walls*** if you like.
OR
**Benjiro**: *Next week I'll come over and help paint the [façade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A7ade)*

Answer (score 2):

Question: "A man is standing outside of my house" or "A man is standing on the outside of my house"? [buzzer]

The first is OK, but we would shorten it:
**A man is standing outside my house**.

"I will paint outside of my house" or "I will paint on the outside of my house".

Neither of those really work for this meaning:

I will paint **the outside** of my house. [as opposed to the inside walls]

**outside can be a noun**: the outside of my house
OR
an adverb of place: **I am outside my house**.

It can also be a preposition or adjective. But I am only giving examples for the question here.